# How to run multi optimizer at the same time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, distributed, supervised-learning

I'm trying to train an ensemble neural network with tensorflow. For example, I have 5 classifiers and each of them is a neural network. I get different samples to train them separately. Thus, I can train them at the same time use a distributed method instead of training them one by one.

The problem is that: I deploy those 5 networks on 5 different devices(5 GPU for example). For each network, I create one Adamoptimizer (which means I have 5 Adamoptimizer totally).

When I'm training this network, first get samples for all networks(if one network need 64 then I get 320 samples).

**Method 1**
Next, I just run:
`sess.run(tf.group(opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, opt5))`
in order to run those 5 optimizers at the same time.

**Method 2**
Another way is to run opts in a for loop:

`opt=[opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, opt5]`

`for i in range(5):`

`sess.run(opt[i])`

However, I try to record the time cost in both ways and found they are almost the same.

So my question is that, if I only use one session and run

`sess.run(tf.group(opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, opt5))`,

will the 5 opts are actually executed one by one instead of at the same time?

And if I want to run them at the same time, what should I do?

By the way, if I just use one session, how fast could I get? Could the time cost in method 1 be 1/5 of method 2? If not, what should I do to achieve that? Should I use multi-sessions, multi-processes, or multi-threads?

Comment: if these five ops are in five different device, then they are run asynchronously, otherwise if they are in same device(like single gpu or cpu), they are run one by one

Comment: I defined those opts in tf.device scope, so I think they are on different devices. But if they are run asynchronously, do you know other reasons why the time cost are similar? For example, Maybe because the communication between the devices are slow?